# error unexpected 'then' on bash script

Tags: bash, shell, debian

on Debian, I am trying to create my first script called user.sh.

To launch it in the shell I type : user.sh USER -add username

i use this kind of relation : USER($1) -add($2) username($3)

COuld you help me to find what's wrong on my code ?

```
if [ $# !=3] ; then                      // check if there are 3 args passed when launching user.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
echo "usage: $0 -add|del name"

else
if [$1 = "USER" ]; then
      if[$2 ="-add" ] ; then
      do adduser $3

      else
      if [$2 ="-dell"] ; then

      do userdel $3

      else echo" The second argument should be "-add" or "-dell"
      fi
    fi
   fi
  fi
```

Thanks

Comment: You missed spaces after `[` on the second and third `if` lines. Also, using proper indentation will help you avoid other issues that might come up with nesting.

Comment: AND why are  you using `do`? Do you have function/script/program installed with that name? If yes, that is not a good idea. `do` is used as part of the shell syntax, change your function/script/program name to something like mydo. If NO, then remove references to `do` in your script, until you get to running `while` loops (.i.e. `while true ; do sleep 5 ; done`! ;-) Good luck.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 2):

It is very important to understand that `[` and `]` are *not* shell metacharacters.  Among other things, that means they do not break words. Also, `[` as a whole word is a command (an alternative name for the `test` command).  Neither it nor `]` is inherently part of shell syntax.

Only these characters separate words (when unquoted): `|` `&` `;` `(` `)` `<` `>` space tab.  Where you need a word break you must use one of them (normally space or tab; these are the only ones whose *sole* significance is to break words).

Additionally, shell comments are introduced by a `#` as the first (and possibly only) character of a word, not by C++-style `//`.

And `do` is a keyword used with `for` constructs.  You've thrown in some extraneous ones.

It looks like this script would perform the job that your original was aiming at:

```
#!/bin/bash

# check if there are 3 args passed when launching user.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
if [ $# != 3 ]; then
  echo "usage: $0 -add|del name"
elif [ "$1" = "USER" ]; then
  if [ "$2" = "-add" ]; then
    adduser "$3"
  elif [ "$2" = "-dell" ]; then
    userdel "$3"
  else
    echo The second argument should be \"-add\" or \"-dell\"
  fi
fi
```

Comment: `USER`, `-add` and `-dell` don't need to be quoted, but `"$1"`, `"$2"` and `"$3"` **do**.

Comment: Same thing is true when using them in the `useradd` and `userdel` calls as well. (In theory, usernames shouldn't contain anything weird, but even with normal usernames, the old code could still break if IFS contained characters that could be found in them).

Comment: Updated to ensure parameter references appear in quotes for safety.  Left unneeded quoting as a stylistic choice.  Escaped quotes in the arguments to `echo`, in a guess as to the OP's intent.

Comment: I still see `adduser $3` as opposed to `adduser "$3"`.

Comment: One more set of quotes added.